# Do you have to upgrade TFS when upgrading Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2010

We'd like to upgrade from VS2010 to SP1, but are not ready to upgrade TFS2010 to SP1. Do we have to wait or can VS be upgraded independently of TFS? Is there any documentation stating this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is no. You don't have to upgrade TFS if you want to use VS2010 SP1, unless they are both installed on the same machine. Brian Harry has written a [comprehensive blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/03/09/installing-all-the-new-stuff.aspx) if you want all the gory details